# How do I make the svg icon and some text in a perfect align status?

Tags: html, css, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/njukyzgj/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="logo-wrapper">

    <div class="logo" style="
max-width: 100px;"><svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="125px" height="125px" viewBox="0 0 125 125"><defs><g id="arl"><path fill="#FEDD76" stroke="none" d="M 34.85 90.25Q 31.85 87.25 29.7 84.05L 9.75 96.2Q 13.4 101.75 18.35 106.7 36.65 125 62.5 125 82.85 125 98.45 113.8L 84.7 94.95Q 75 101.7 62.5 101.7 46.3 101.7 34.85 90.25 Z"></path><path fill="#83D9F0" stroke="none" d="M 61.3 23.35L 61.3 0Q 36.2 0.4 18.35 18.3 0 36.6 0 62.5 0 80.1 8.5 94.15L 28.4 82Q 23.35 73.3 23.35 62.5 23.35 46.3 34.85 34.85 45.9 23.75 61.3 23.35 Z"></path><path fill="#FB9CBE" stroke="none" d="M 90.25 90.25Q 88.5 91.95 86.65 93.45L 100.35 112.3Q 103.65 109.75 106.7 106.7 124.6 88.85 125 63.75L 101.7 63.75Q 101.3 79.15 90.25 90.25 Z"></path><path fill="#F66864" stroke="none" d="M 84.45 30Q 91.25 20.5 98.1 11 83.05 0.35 63.75 0L 63.75 23.35Q 75.3 23.65 84.45 30 Z"></path><path fill="#81BE94" stroke="none" d="M 106.7 18.3Q 103.5 15.1 100.05 12.45 93.2 21.9 86.4 31.35 86.35 31.35 86.35 31.4 88.4 33 90.25 34.85 101.3 45.9 101.7 61.3L 125 61.3Q 124.6 36.2 106.7 18.3 Z"></path></g></defs><g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,0) "><use xlink:href="#arl"></use></g></svg></div>
    <div class="slogan">
      <h1>A Logo Website!</h1>
      <h2 class="weblink">mylogo.com</h2>
      <h3>something to say here</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{font-family:"Tahoma"}
.logo{float:left;width:30%}
.slogan{float:left}
h1, h2, h3{margin:0}
#logo-wrapper{width:100%}
```

What I want:

1. the `.logo` always take 30% of its parent div `#logo-wrapper` while the `.slogan` takes the rest.
2. as the width getting smaller, (i.e on a mobile device), the `.logo` will shrink to let the `.slogan` have enough room
3. the two part will be vertically aligned to middle.

I tried many ways but can't get what I want.

Comment: then why you don't you use .slogan{width:70%;float:right;} its mean now .logo is using 30% from 100% and .slogan use 70% from 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `max-width: 100px;` from

```
<div class="logo" style=" max-width: 100px;">
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njukyzgj/2/)

**Edit:**

To make vertical middle give `display: table-cell;` and  `display: table-cell;` to both class. `.logo` and `.slogan` and remove `float:left`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njukyzgj/3/)

Comment: Then you can use media query for that. For smaller screen make logo width smaller. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: thanks, but when I make it smaller it's not vertically aligned to the right part.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo I have update my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

paste this code in your fiddle and check..i have already checked it it is working as your expect

```
  <table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
  <td style="width: 30%;">
    <div class="logo"><svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="125px" height="125px" viewBox="0 0 125 125"><defs><g id="arl"><path fill="#FEDD76" stroke="none" d="M 34.85 90.25Q 31.85 87.25 29.7 84.05L 9.75 96.2Q 13.4 101.75 18.35 106.7 36.65 125 62.5 125 82.85 125 98.45 113.8L 84.7 94.95Q 75 101.7 62.5 101.7 46.3 101.7 34.85 90.25 Z"></path><path fill="#83D9F0" stroke="none" d="M 61.3 23.35L 61.3 0Q 36.2 0.4 18.35 18.3 0 36.6 0 62.5 0 80.1 8.5 94.15L 28.4 82Q 23.35 73.3 23.35 62.5 23.35 46.3 34.85 34.85 45.9 23.75 61.3 23.35 Z"></path><path fill="#FB9CBE" stroke="none" d="M 90.25 90.25Q 88.5 91.95 86.65 93.45L 100.35 112.3Q 103.65 109.75 106.7 106.7 124.6 88.85 125 63.75L 101.7 63.75Q 101.3 79.15 90.25 90.25 Z"></path><path fill="#F66864" stroke="none" d="M 84.45 30Q 91.25 20.5 98.1 11 83.05 0.35 63.75 0L 63.75 23.35Q 75.3 23.65 84.45 30 Z"></path><path fill="#81BE94" stroke="none" d="M 106.7 18.3Q 103.5 15.1 100.05 12.45 93.2 21.9 86.4 31.35 86.35 31.35 86.35 31.4 88.4 33 90.25 34.85 101.3 45.9 101.7 61.3L 125 61.3Q 124.6 36.2 106.7 18.3 Z"></path></g></defs><g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,0) "><use xlink:href="#arl"></use></g></svg></div>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 70%;">
    <div class="slogan">
  <h1>A Logo Website!</h1>
  <h2 class="weblink">mylogo.com</h2>
  <h3>something to say here</h3>
</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```